# Data model value providers in Lightning Components - any insight or links to more information?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The [aura:expression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_expression.htm) documentation mentions these value providers:

> Value providers include m (data from model), v (attribute data from
>   component), and c (controller action).

but I have only ever seen `v.` and `c.` in examples.

(In AngularJS 1.x, the model is simple JavaScript objects and the view updates based on the model. Something closer to that in Lightning Components would be welcome.)

Anyone have any insight or links to information about `m.`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just my guess: Looks like model was an initial thought that got scrapped off /used for debugging purposes only.

From one of the docs:

Model

> **Some components you see might have a Model section. Models are a deprecated feature and they are included simply for debugging
>   purposes. Don't reference models or your code will break.**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_components.htm?search_text=model