# Lightning value providers !c. !v. and !m.?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I just checked the Lightning component docs and [found this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_expression.htm):

> An expression uses a value provider to access data and can also use
>   operators and functions for more complex expressions. Value providers
>   include m (data from model), v(attribute data from component), and c
>   (controller action). This example show an expression {!v.num} whose
>   value is resolved by the attribute num.

I've never seen {!m.fooBar} where is this used and what kind of Data/information is stored in m? couldn't find anything in google.

Comment: According to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166508/data-model-value-providers-in-lightning-components-any-insight-or-links-to-mor) answer here on a similar question. It is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"m" has been deprecated, as mentioned in the other answer, but you can always look at [Value Providers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm) for a current list, which includes `c`, `v`, `globalID`, `$Label`, `$Browser`, `$Locale` and `$Resource`. You can also write your own value providers as I demonstrated [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180007) and Mohith demonstrated [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150411). Custom value providers may be useful if you want to implement brand-new features into your markup via expression evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

The model value provider seems to be deprecated. The docs recommend that you don't reference it or it could cause your code to break:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_components.htm?search_text=model